# Regular expression : parse html to certain html

Tags: c#, regex

We having a HTML content like

```
<em></ em > 
<font style="text-align:justify;">aaaaaaaaaaa</font>
<img src="abc.jpg"/>
<iframe src="somelink.com"> 
</iframe>
<br>
<br/>
```

We want to change all HTML Tags to `<p></p>`

but do not change the `<img/>` and `<br/>` tag, some `<br/>` tags may display `<br>`

so, the following is our expected result:

```
<p></p> 
<p>aaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<img src="abc.jpg"/>
<p> 
</p>
<br>
<br/>
```

My regular expression like (in C#):

```
String result = Regex.Replace(content, @"<[^/b>]*>", "<p>");
result = Regex.Replace(result, @"</[^>]*>", "</p>");
```

but it can't skip the certain tags,
please help me, thanks !

Comment: `d.*t p.*s.*e h.*l w.*h r.*g.*x`

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML changes, use jQuery, or some similar HTML parsing library/functions. [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: @Tushar Okay - but what library supports a replace operation of any kind of tag to a specified tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

[`<(?<close>/?)((?!img|br).)*?>`](http://goo.gl/YKTteV)

and replace with:

`<${close}p>`

[CODE SAMPLE](http://ideone.com/TgAqJi)

Comment: It has a more character '?' in the end of 
<${close}p>?